# Unable to import new Swift Charts framework into macOS project

Tags: swift, charts

I would like to be able to use the new Charts framework in a Mac app.  Unfortunately when I enter import Charts it is not recognized.  If I create a new project for iOS it allows me to do so.  Is Charts not available for macOS or am I missing some step to make it work?
I have also noticed that NavigationStack is not available.

Comment: Are you on macOS 13? Are you on Xcode 14?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: try this: `import Charts` instead of your `Import Charts`

Comment: import Charts does not work.  My error for listing it as Import Charts in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Charts you have to have macOS 13 Ventura SDK.  It is not available in Xcode 14.0.1. You have to install Xcode 14.1 RC 2 or later to use Swift Charts in macOS Ventura.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Charts

https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/#minimum-requirements